# In Vulkan is an execution dependency not enough to ensure proper order?

Tags: vulkan

I'm having trouble understanding why we specify stages of the pipeline for the pipeline barrier as well as access mask. The point of specifying a barrier with pipeline stages is to give instructions that all commands before a certain stage happen before all stages after a certain stage. So with this reasoning let's say I want to transfer data from a staging buffer to a device-local buffer. Before I read that buffer from a shader I need to have a barrier saying that the transfer stage must take place before the shader read stage after it. I can do this with:

srcstage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT;
dststage = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_BIT;

This is supposed to say that all commands before the barrier must complete the transfer stage before all commands after the barrier start the fragment shader stage.

However I don't understand the concept of access mask and why we use it together with the stage mask. Apparently the stage masks don't ensure "visibility" or "availability"??? So is it the case that this means that although the transfer stage will complete before the fragment stage will start there is no guarantee that the shader will read the proper data? Because maybe caches have not been flushed and not been made visible/available?

If that's the case and we need to specify access masks such as:

srcaccessmask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_WRITE_BIT;
dstaccessmask = VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_READ_BIT;

Then what is even the point of specifying stages if the stages isn't enough, and it comes down to the access mask?

Answer (score 2):

Access masks ensure visibility, but you cannot have visibility over something that is not yet available (ie: you cannot see what hasn't happened yet). Visibility and availability are both necessary for a memory barrier, but each alone is *insufficient*.

After all, execution barriers do not strictly speaking need memory barriers. A write-after-read barrier does not need to ensure visibility. It simply needs to make sure that no reads happen after the write; a pure execution barrier is sufficient. But if you're doing a write-after-write or a read-after-write, then you need to ensure visibility *in addition to* availability.

Answer (score 1):

Execution dependency is not enough to ensure proper order simply because Vulkan's memory model is such that it requires manual\explicit [memory barriers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier).

In other words, execution barrier only covers execution, but not side-effects of the execution. So you also need memory barrier(s) when you need the side-effects to be coherent\consistent.

If the coherency is satisfied another way, the access mask is actually what is unnecessary:

```
semaphore_wait.pWaitDstStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
// we need to order our stuff after the semaphore wait, so:
barrier.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT;
// semaphore already includes all device memory access, so nothing here:
barrier.srcAccessMask = 0;
barrier.oldLayout = COOL_LAYOUT;
barrier.newLayout = EVEN_BETTER_LAYOUT;
```

Using only access masks (without stage) would be ambiguous. Access masks can limit the amount of memory coherency work the driver needs to perform:

```
// make available the storage writes from fragment shader,
// but do not bother with storage writes
// from compute, vertex, tessellation, geometry, raytracing, or mesh shader:
barrier.srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT;
barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_SHADER_WRITE_BIT;
```

`VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT` does implicitly include vertex, tessellation, and geormetry shader stage. But only for execution dependency purposes, and **not** for memory dependency:

> **Note**
>
> Including a particular pipeline stage in the first synchronization scope of a command implicitly includes logically earlier pipeline stages in the synchronization scope. Similarly, the second synchronization scope includes logically later pipeline stages.
>
> However, note that access scopes are not affected in this way - only the precise stages specified are considered part of each access scope.

Comment: specifying access of VK_ACCESS_SHADER_WRITE_BIT with stage VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT doesn't make visible writes from earlier stages such as vertex shader? Huh? What would you need to do if you wanted vertex shader or earlier writes made visible?

Comment: @Zebrafish You would need to explicitly add the pipeline stage to stage mask if you want it included in memory dependency. Which partially answers your original question what the stage mask is for.

Comment: I was under the impression that you gave would specify "ONE" stage, everything up to and including that stage would be completed in the first scope. You're saying if I want writes to be visible from the transfer stage AND the fragment shader stage I would have to specify the transfer stage and fragment stage bitwise or'ed together? In the case you specify multiple stages, is the first synchronisation scope up to latest stage bitwise or'ed together? In other words with transfer and fragment stage together, the execution dependency is everything before fragment shader.

Comment: @Zebrafish No, you can give arbitrary number of flags to a bitfield. Yes, e.g. `srcStageMask = VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT | VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT`. Transfer and fragment shader do not have any logical order between themselves (they are different pipelines), so you would have to do that either way.

Comment: If I specify srcstage as VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT | VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT that means that the access masks apply to only those stages, and the 'before' synchronisation scope includes all stages before the latest one, the fragment shader, right?

Comment: @Zebrafish If you supply `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_VERTEX_SHADER_BIT | VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT`, that means the memory dependency applies to only those two stages and none other. E.g. `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_GEOMETRY_SHADER_BIT` is implicitly part of this execution dependency, but **not** part of this memory dependency. So if it was paired with `VK_ACCESS_MEMORY_WRITE_BIT`, it would cover writes by the vertex and fragment, but none other (such as geometry).

Comment: @Zebrafish Nevertheless if some previous synchronization links to `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_GEOMETRY_SHADER_BIT`, then execution dependency chain would still successfully be formed, as if you added that bit to the parameter (because it is added implicitly, because it is logically-earlier stage to `FRAGMENT`, but only for the purposes of **execution** dependency.